# Change Page in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

As a question title, I want to change page (in same window) using [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) from renderer process.

- How to do that?

I have *home* and *customer* page from home I want to go to customer page vice versa.

Comment: Mostly you do this the same way it is done in a normal web browser, is this not working for you? In addition to all the ways you normally can change a page you could also get at the BrowserWindow instance through the remote module and call the loadUrl method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use webContents object. It has loadURL method, that can change you page content.

```
const template = [
    {
        label: 'Edit',
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'I want change smth',
                click(item, focusedWindow) {
                    window.webContents.loadURL('https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md');
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]

const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template)
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally i did with my approach. I develop using angularJS by implementing single page application. By this, I can change page using `ui-router`. So, `electron` just make my html code running on desktop.